# Rails - how can I make a profile switch on a radio button using a device and polymorphic associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, polymorphic-associations

I am new to development on rails. I need help with customizing the device. I have user with polymorphic association - profilable. When registering, I need to fill in the profilable depending on the selected radio button.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  protected

  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: %i[email profilable])
  end

  def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: %i[email])
  end
end
```

model User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  belongs_to :profilable, polymorphic: true

  def set_client_profile
    c = ClientProfile.new
    self.profilable = c
  end

  def set_realtor_profile
    r = RealtorProfile.new
    self.profilable = r
  end
end
```

model ClientProfile

```
class ClientProfile < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user, as: :profilable
end
```

model RealtorProfile

```
class RealtorProfile < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user, as: :profilable
end
```

and this in my *views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb*

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :profilable, 'Client' %>
    <%= f.radio_button :profilable, 'Client' %>
    <%= f.label :profilable, 'Realtor' %>
    <%= f.radio_button :profilable, 'Realtor'%>
    <% if params[:profilable] == 'Client' %>
      <% resource.set_client_profile %>
    <% else %> 
      <% resource.set_realtor_profile %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

This is error after registration:

***1 error prohibited this user from being saved:***
***Profilable must exist***

sorry for this horrible code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of code

```
 <% if params[:profilable] == 'Client' %>
      <% resource.set_client_profile %>
    <% else %> 
      <% resource.set_realtor_profile %>
    <% end %>
```

will be executed only on view rendering. The `resource` here is a an empty model that you use only for creating a form. This instance is not an actual model that will be created after the `create` request hits the server.
So, both `set_client_profile` and `set_client_profile`  will be never called in `create` method of the controller. This code should be removed.

I guess the easiest way to do it is to redefine `create` method in `Users::RegistrationsController`. The original code of this method can be found in the [repo](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb).
So, it can be modified like this:

```rb
 def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    #here comes your modification
    if sign_up_params[:profilable] == 'Client'
      resource.set_client_profile
    else
      resource.set_realtor_profile
    end

    resource.save
    # After that, copy the rest of the original `create` method
    ...
```